# The "elseif" section of my VBA code works but not the "if"

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to adjust the decimals of many values in an excel worksheet.
The objectives were:
- For values higher than 100, no decimals;
- For values lower than 100 but higher than 10, one decimal; and,
- For values lower than 10, two decimals

I thought using VBA would be simple enough, even though I never used it before. Unfortunately I was wrong. Please see my code below. For some reasons, only the "elseif" section of the code is working. For values lower than 100, the decimals are adjusted correctly. It is not the case for the "if" section of my code though.

It also seems that the code works in cells outside the range (A1:D11) (as long as I select them); which is good since my worksheet is pretty big. I don't understand why though.

I would appreciate if you could shed some light on these mysteries.

```
Sub adjust_decimal()
'
'
'

'
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:D11")
  If cell.Value > 100 Then
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0;General"
  ElseIf cell.Value < 100 Then
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[<10]0.00;[<100]0.0;General"
  End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen for values that are 100 exactly? In any event, why not just use conditional formatting rather than VBA?

Comment: They will stay at 100. No decimal. Well I could use conditional formatting if I only had one worksheet. But I have many more.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you could use just one line of code and do something like  `Range("A1:D11").NumberFormat="[<10]0.00;[<100]0.0;0"`. And apply those rules to all cells at once.

Comment: Hi Foxfire! Thanks a lot for your input. It works just fine! Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single line of code:

`Range("A1:D11").NumberFormat="[<10]0.00;[<100]0.0;0"`.

With this rule, numbers below 10 will have 2 decimals, numbers equal or higher than 10 but below 100 will have 1 decimal, and any other case will be a integer.

Please, notice that this applies only to format,**it does not change the value at all**. If the value is 200,55 you'll see it as 201, but the numeric value used in any calculations involving that cell will use 200,55, not 201.